# Bash CLI remove quotes from output of a command

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I am trying to load a JSON file using `jq` per [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html). It is quite straightforward and this works:

```
$ cat ~/Downloads/json.txt | jq '.name'
"web"
```

However, I need to assign the output of this variable to a command. I tried to do this and this works:

```
$ my_json=`cat ~/Downloads/json.txt | jq '.name'`
$ myfile=~/Downloads/$my_json.txt
$ echo $myfile
/home/qut/Downloads/"web".txt
```

But I want `/home/qut/Downloads/web.txt`.

How do I remove the quotes, i.e. change `"web"` to `web`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [tr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tr.1.html) command to remove the quotes:

```
my_json=$(cat ~/Downloads/json.txt | jq '.name' | tr -d \")
```

Comment: Thank you for the `tr` command... I looked through 4 different posts with hundreds of upvotes with people writing 40+ character mega-one-liners to get the job done. You have the correct (and probably modern) solution.

Answer (score 29):

In the particular case of `jq`, you can specify that the output should be in *raw* format:

```
   --raw-output / -r:

   With this option, if the filter´s result is a string then  it  will
   be  written directly to standard output rather than being formatted
   as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq fil‐
   ters talk to non-JSON-based systems.
```

To illustrate using the sample `json.txt` file from [your link](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html):

```
$ jq '.name' json.txt
"Google"
```

whereas

```
$ jq -r '.name' json.txt
Google
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more simple and efficient, using the native shell prefix/suffix removal feature:

```
my_json=$(cat ~/Downloads/json.txt | jq '.name')
    temp="${my_json%\"}"
    temp="${temp#\"}"
    echo "$temp"
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733338/shell-script-remove-first-and-last-quote-from-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval echo` like this:

```
my_json=$(eval echo $(cat ~/Downloads/json.txt | jq '.name'))
```

but this is not ideal - could easily cause bugs and/or security flaws.